# Why children function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="entityClass" ...
    <div class="linksClass" ...
         <img class="collapseClass"
```

I'm trying using JQuery to get the `img` child:

```
// _this is entityClass div
var image = $(_this).children(".collapseClass");
```

but it returns `0` in length!

Any help

Comment: What is `_this`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Unicron, he specified that in a comment.

Comment: _this is the parameter name of my function

Comment: @John and what does `_this` refer to? Are you sure it points to the correct element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`children` refers to the **immediate** children. You want to use `find` instead, which searches **all descendants**:

```
var image = $(_this).find(".collapseClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? 
`$('.linksClass').children('collapseClass')`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="collapseClass"> is NOT child of <div class="entityClass" ....
```

You can use 
var image = $(_this).**find**(".collapseClass");